# 'nulla' vs. 'niente'

Tags: word-usage

Non so se si possa generalizzare, e forse ci sono differenze regionali d'uso, ma ho l'impressione che 'nulla' sia più determinativo di 'niente'.

Per esempio, ritenete che la frase 'non ho nulla da dire' abbia lo stesso significato di 'non ho niente da dire'?

Oppure ritenete che con 'nulla' si esprima una completa chiusura dell'argomento, mentre con 'niente' il parlante lasci la possibilità di un'ulteriore interlocuzione?

Comment: Non riesco a vedere alcuna differenza. Il dizionario Treccani è d'accordo con me: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/nulla/

Comment: @egreg, sì, dal vocabolario non emergono differenze, però nell'uso ...

Comment: Non mi pare, a parte una differenza tra regioni nella frequenza di una parola rispetto all'altra.

Comment: assolutamente nessuna differenza.

Comment: Anche da Roma, nessuna differenza.

Comment: la differenza di frequenza d'uso genera una diversa percezione

Comment: Ci sono differenze significative nell'uso in alcuni linguaggi tecnici. Ad esempio l'uso di `lista/albero nullo/vuoto` ma mai nessuna frase di senso simile che usi `niente`. Questo però è probabilmente dovuto ad un'influenza dell'inglese...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Nulla" e "niente" hanno il medesimo significato, tuttavia è vero che "nulla" sia percepibile come di peso differente e farei risalire il ciò sia ai differenti domini in cui "nulla" rimane maggiormente usato dando la sfumatura di 'vuoto', come dice @kiamlaluno, quali la filosofia e la letteratura, sia all'uso maggiore che "Niente" pare avere nelle espressioni gergali e comunque non formali (forse questa seconda motivazione è probabilmente correlata alla prima)

Answer (score 5):

Nel contesto indicato nella domanda, non c'è differenza tra "nulla" e "niente". In tutti e due i casi, chi scrive (o dice) quelle frasi intende che non c'è niente che debba dire; niente è detto (anche implicitamente) a proposito di quanto la stessa persona possa dire in futuro.

Generalmente parlando, "nulla" è usato in contesti dove "niente" non è usato; per esempio, parlando del concetto filosofico, la frase usata è "il nulla".